# NetBeans ghost icon meaning

Tags: netbeans

I was just wondering what this icon in NetBeans means. To me it looks like a little ghost. I couldn't find it in any lists of the icons.

[image: ghost icon]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats the java mascot, duke!
http://www.oracle.com/us/technologies/java/duke-424174.html

He was the first mascot introduced to java. Now we have a stupid cup of java. Bring back duke!